# Canvas FillText non-const compiler error

Tags: canvas, c++builder-xe6

In BDS XE6 I am trying yo put text using Canvas->FillText.
I have some issues with const declaration and am not able to overcome the problem.

```
TRect *Rect = new TRect(0, 0, 100, 30);
Canvas->FillText(*Rect, "Hello", false, 100, TFillTextFlags() << TFillTextFlag::RightToLeft, TTextAlign::Center, TTextAlign::Center);
```

I get the compiler error:

```
[bcc32 Error] MyForm.cpp(109): E2522 Non-const function _fastcall TCanvas::FillText(const TRectF &,const UnicodeString,const bool, const float,const TFillTextFlags,const TTextAlign,const TTextAlign) called for const object
  Full parser context
    LavEsiti.cpp(107): parsing: void _fastcall TMyForm::MyGridDrawColumnCell(TObject *,const TCanvas *,const TColumn *,const TRectF &,const int,const TValue &,const TGridDrawStates)
```

I'd like to get some info on my mistake. Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> TRect *Rect = new TRect(0, 0, 100, 30);

You do not need to dynamically allocate the `TRect`, use a stack-based instance instead:

```
TRect Rect(0, 0, 100, 30);
Canvas->FillText(Rect, ...);
```

Or, use the `Rect()` function without a variable at all:

```
Canvas->FillText(Rect(0, 0, 100, 30), ...);
```

> I get the compiler error:
>   [bcc32 Error] MyForm.cpp(109): E2522 Non-const function _fastcall TCanvas::FillText(const TRectF &,const UnicodeString,const bool, const float,const TFillTextFlags,const TTextAlign,const TTextAlign) called for const object

Delphi (which the VCL is written in) has no concept of `const`-ness for class methods, like C++ does.  The `Canvas` parameter of the `OnDrawColumnCell` event is declared as `const` (I do not know why), but the `TCanvas::FillText()` method is not declared as `const`.  That is why you get the `Non-const function ... called for const object` error.  Delphi has no problem with that, but C++ does.

As you already discovered, you can `const_cast` the error away, but that is more of a hack than a solution.  The event handler should not be declaring an object pointer as `const` to begin with, that is an oversight on whoever wrote that event in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by calling function with const_cast option:

```
const_cast<TCanvas*>(Canvas)->FillText(*Rect, "Hello", false, 100, TFillTextFlags() << TFillTextFlag::RightToLeft, TTextAlign::Center, TTextAlign::Center);
```